# Achieving this layout in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to achieve something like this in flutter. I have a horizontal scrollable which has these rounded containers. I want the width of these containers to shrink if the elements in the scrollable is more than 3 and it should expand as per the image if the elements are less than 2. What i want is exactly like this image, i have been reading about flexible widget but when i wrap it inside a scrollable row it gives layout specific issues. Any workaround to achieve this?[image]

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                ...List.generate(
                  9,
                  (index) => Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            ...List.generate(
                2,
                (index) => Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                          height: 100,
                          width: 180,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                    ))
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 350,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

The above build method produces the following result.(The values here are hardcoded and is just for demonstration). The list values are going to be dynamic and the desired result should be like the one in the video. How do i proceed with this?

https://streamable.com/w142je

Comment: Please share [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you better

Comment: @rckrd i have made the edits, could you please have a look? Thanks in advance.. We can have further discussion on this if you want...

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: MyHomePage());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String hintText = 'hing';
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var list1 = List.filled(2, '2');
    var list2 = List.filled(4, '4');
    var list3 = List.filled(1, '1');

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            _getList(context, list1),
            _getList(context, list2),
            _getList(context, list3),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getList(BuildContext context, List<String> list) {
    bool ownSize = list.length == 2;
    if (ownSize) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          children: list.map((t) => rowItem(t, 250)).toList(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Row(
        children: list
            .map(
              (t) => Expanded(child: rowItem(t)),
            )
            .toList(),
      );
    }
  }

  Widget rowItem(String text, [double? width]) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      height: 100,
      width: width,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]